# Superfish vs. Corporate MITM

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle

I work for a consulting company, and I have been implementing a tool from a security vendor, which is a cloud proxy for all user traffic. It will perform malware scanning and filtering of all web traffic. It works by enforcing a proxy autoconfiguration file to redirect HTTP/HTTPS traffic to one of the vendor's global data centers. We, of course, need to deploy certificates to each workstation in order to proxy HTTPS traffic and perform the MITM for malware scanning.

My question: how is this different from Superfish installing a root cert? I've been reading about how the private key for Superfish is stored on the machine. I assume corporate MITM attacks do not have this same vulnerability, but how does the architecture work differently in a corporate environment?

Comment: Are you asking about vulnerabilities in SuperFish itself, or vulnerabilities in clients with SuperFish installed? (e.g. "it completely breaks HTTPS security" leads to vulnerabilities in the entire system, but it's not exactly a vulnerability in SuperFish itself [but it is a *bug* in SuperFish itself])

Answer (score 40):

What makes Superfish, and similar products (all herein just referred to as "Superfish"), different from corporate MitM is that Superfish is doing the MitM on the client machine. Corporate MitM is performed on a separate server or appliance.

This is important because the system performing the MitM must have the *private key* of a Trusted Root CA in order to work. (Strictly speaking, the Root CA doesn't need to be trusted. But the user will see red flags if it's not.)

For Superfish, that means the key has to be on the client device - one which is notoriously not well-maintained and generally very vulnerable to attacks.

For corporate MitMs, the key is on the monitoring server - typically maintained by experienced personnel who perform regular maintenance and do not do things (e.g.: web browsing, downloading extra software, opening documents, etc.) that would expose the system to unnecessary risk.

However, all SSL proxies (corporate or otherwise) still need to be carefully implemented to account for the fact that they are removing the client's ability to self-validate the remote system's certificate. Particularly this means:

1. The SSL proxy *must* properly validate the remote systems' certificates and either appropriately warn the user or drop the connection entirely when something is amiss. As Charles Duffy mentioned in the comments, properly validating certificates also requires that the proxy does not trust its own built-in CA.
2. Ideally, the SSL proxy should also do some integrity verification against historical or community-aggregated reference certificates. This is implemented in some web browser extensions, and under normal circumstances can be manually performed by the user, to help detect fraudulent use of otherwise-trustworty Root CAs. Since the SSL proxy removes the user's ability to do this themselves, or to effectively use a browser extension for this purpose, it would be best if the proxy could do its own checking to compensate. (Though I doubt this is available in most corporate MitM products.)

Another thing you need to be careful about, since you mentioned that this service is provided to you by an outside vendor, is that the SSL proxy can see all of your users' traffic as if it was unencrypted. (That's the very purpose of an SSL proxy.) This means that data you would otherwise want to have protected from third-party viewers is going to be fully visible by the vendor should they choose to abuse your trust.

Comment: Also, when working in a corporate realm the users are most likely informed that this proxying is occurring, and they consent to such monitoring.  While no mention of this was made to Lenovo users.  Unless it was buried in a EULA somewhere.

Comment: @raz Fair point.

Comment: OH WOW! Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand my confusion. This entire time, I just assumed that Superfish was a PROXY. Now it makes perfect sense to me - thanks much. Superfish is really just an ad injection server and not at all a proxy. Now I get why the private key  must be on the client machine. THANK YOU!

In hindsight, it would definitely not make sense as a proxy architecture given the globally dispersed nature of Lenovo PC sales. This would cause way too much latency, not to mention the overhead involved would exceed ad revenue. I'm a bit embarrassed now! :)

Comment: @jvonscha Superfish *is* a proxy. It's just a *local* (i.e.: running on the same machine as the client) proxy. It has to use an SSL proxy to inject the ads into HTTPS sites. The only other way is to actually inject itself into the browser process. It's just probably easier to write one SSL interceptor than it is to write (at least) four browser plugins.

Comment: In hindsight, it would definitely not make sense with a remote proxy architecture given the globally dispersed nature of Lenovo PC sales. This would cause too much latency, not to mention the overhead involved would exceed ad revenue. I'm a bit embarrassed now! :)

Comment: Understood on local proxy! I should have said I assumed Superfish was a remote proxy, not just a proxy.

Comment: @raz: I would guess that most users don't realize that, e.g. when they check their bank balance at work, their employer can see everything. Of course, the users probably signed agreements allowing for such monitoring, but still I think they often don't realize exactly what that means... I'm constantly explaining this to non-tech people.

Comment: @mehaase The users signed agreements, and many corporate policies require that the systems notify them at each login (e.g.: a "warning banner"). If the users claim oblivion beyond that point, it's their own fault. That said, there's also a lot of places that put an allowance for monitoring in the AUP and system notice but don't actually do SSL proxy.

Comment: @raz - 100% they don't! Whenever I tell our users this who do not work in security, they are shocked. I have mixed feelings. I don't like to ever see 3rd parties cracking SSL, especially when users are not aware. At the same time, it is the property of the corporation, and the enterprise has every right to protect its infrastructure by cracking SSL for malware scanning (especially when attacks are increasingly coming over SSL). The key is users need to be properly educated, and if they are not OK with it, then they should not be checking banking/etc. sites on their corporate-owned machines.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that it is far my difficult to pass these corporate policies in countries like Germany.

Comment: @jvonscha: Agree with you 100%. If companies really wanted to be transparent about what they are doing, they would insert some HTML into intercepted web pages saying, "this page is monitored by your employer, click <here> for more info." Most IT depts I have seen aren't interested in that kind of transparency.

Comment: @Iszi "it's their own fault" Unfortunately, your myopic attitude towards users is far too common in the security industry. Do you read every 30 page AUP before you sign up for a web site? No, you don't. And users don't carefully read the AUP they sign at work. They just want the job.

Comment: @mehaase The problem there is a 30-page AUP. A good AUP is like a good resume. One or two pages, tops. Don't drown the user in crap they'll never read.

Comment: Another important distinguishing difference is that a good corporate proxy *won't trust its own CA*, if it sees that CA used by a server on the Internet-facing side. That Superfish didn't reject its own certificate when sees _past_ its own proxy is part of what made it so dangerous even if its authors weren't malicious (or coopted by malicious parties) themselves.

Comment: Surely the main problem is that *all installations of SuperFish use the same certificate*, and therefore if you have the private key from any installation, you have the private key of all installations.

Comment: @immibis No, that only exacerbates the problem described by Charles. If Superfish was configured to not trust its own CA when validating external sites, a leak of the Superfish key wouldn't even be an issue. Besides, there still remains the other problem of Superfish not performing proper certificate validation to begin with. There's ways to trick Superfish into accepting any certificate you give it regardless of the CA, which means that you don't even need Superfish's key to do a MitM attack.

Comment: @Iszi right, that's the other main part of the problem. However, the problem is *not* that the key is on the client device. (It might be a problem if you were trying to use it as a corporate proxy, but it's not when used for its intended purpose)

Comment: @immibis If the proxy is properly implemented, being on the client may not be a "problem" but it nonetheless still increases the risk of the proxy being compromised.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between Superfish and a Corporate Proxy is how the new SSL certificate is generated.

In the Superfish case, the CA certificate **and** the private key stands on the client computer, and the software generates a new SSL certificate with a key it have on itself. The traffic is intercepted locally, a new certificate is generated on the client, and sent to the browser. Anyone having access to debug tools can extract the certificate and the key, because they are both on the client computer.

In the Corporate Proxy case, the CA Certificate will be installed on every client computer, but the private key resides on the proxy server. If the server is have adequate protection, the key will not be compromised. The traffic is intercepted on the proxy server, and sent with a new certificate to the client. It's not possible to extract the private key on the client, because the key is only on the server.

Comment: It's worse than that. Superfish uses the *same* certificate on all systems, it doesn't generate a new one for each installation. The passphrase used to secure the private key is 'komodia', a string found in the code and not protected at all (and the name of the company that produced the proxy code). That means anyone can create a MitM attack against *all* machines with Superfish installed, not just a specific machine.

Comment: @MikeDimmick And it's that latter bit that moves Superfish from "ethically and professionally dubious design decisions" to "criminally negligent", in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

while the other amswers are correct about implementation details,  the security issue in play is one of authorization.

In the case of Superfish and related stuffs, the system owner typically doesn't want Superfish to be able to read all the stuff that is sent and received via HTTPS.  On your home computer,  you probably don't want Superfish to have your credit card details,  online health details,  etc. In a corporation, you typically don't want Superfish to be able to konitor everything you access for business purposes, like when accessing corporate web email clients or when researching something for a trade secret.  Also, superfish does all this somewhat surreptitiously in that it's installed before you ever get the computer and you aren't warned that it's in place,  so you have no opportunity to authorize or reject its use.

With a corporate MitM,  the company is the system owner.,  not the end user,  and not Superfish. The company,  in an attempt to improve security sets up a proxy server that is authorized and whose risks and value has been accepted.

It's  not that the basic idea of a proxy is necessarily bad.  It's that an unauthorized proxy that allows unauthorized companies/imdividuals to access your stuff is bad.